# How to fetch unique rows returned by PFQuery.queryWithClassName?

Tags: ios, rubymotion, parse-platform

Im studying parse.com sdk and I would like to know if there is any way can fetch data distinctly?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it in the PFQuery at this time.

https://www.parse.com/questions/retrieving-unique-values

You will need to iterate through the returned results and find distinct values yourself.